# How to extract value from json in Snowflake

Tags: json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a varchar field in a table and the data is coming into that field in this format.

`{:old_id=>{:id=>"12345", :create_date=>Mon, 15 May 2023, :amount=>50.0}, :new_id=>{:id=>nil, :create_date=>"2023-05-15", :amount=>"50.00"}}`

I want to extract the the two ids i.e. `id=>"12345"` and `id=>nil`

Need help extracting the id field

I don't know if this is considered JSON format. I tried doing parse_json on this field but getting `Error parsing JSON: misplaced colon, pos 2` error.

Tried try_parse_json as well but get NULL value

Comment: this is not JSON, but a regexp could be used to change `:old_id=>` to `"old_id":`

Comment: If possible, it would be best to fix "data coming in into that field in this format" and make it properly write a standard format instead (like JSON). Anything else is putting perfume on a pile of poop. (Granted, sometimes you have no choice than to put perfume on a pile of poop.)

Comment: Thanks @Amadan. Agree with what you are saying. I went back to our source system and asked them to provide the data in a better way.  As I dug more into the data, I found that the formatting of information coming in was inconsistent and did not provide for a good way to untangle information

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a Ruby hash formatted string - we can use a series of regular expressions to transform it into a JSON string using Python (as seen in https://stackoverflow.com/a/76519482/132438).

Then we can bring this into a Snowflake Python UDF, so you can use it to parse the string inside your SQL functions:

```sql
create or replace function ruby_hash_to_json(input_str string)
returns string
language python
runtime_version = 3.10
handler = 'x'
as 
$$
import re
def x(input_str):
    input_str = input_str.replace('=>', ':')
    input_str = input_str.replace(':nil', ':null')  # JSON uses null, not None

    # Remove weekday from date string and add quotes around date
    input_str = re.sub(r'\w+, (\d{2} \w{3} \d{4})', r'"\1"', input_str)

    # Convert Ruby's symbols (words preceded by a colon) into valid JSON keys (quoted words)
    # This handles symbols both at the beginning of the string and in other positions.
    input_str = re.sub(r'({|, ):(\w+)', r'\1"\2"', input_str)

    return input_str
    # Convert the string to dictionary
    output_dict = json.loads(input_str)

    return output_dict
$$;
```

In action:

```sql
with data as (
    select $${:old_id=>{:id=>"12345", :create_date=>Mon, 15 May 2023, :amount=>50.0}, :new_id=>{:id=>nil, :create_date=>"2023-05-15", :amount=>"50.00"}}$$ x
)

select parse_json(ruby_hash_to_json(x)) parsed, parsed:old_id.id, parsed:new_id.id
from data
;
```

[image]