# How do I convert a Ruby hash string into a JSON string using Python?

Tags: python, ruby, parsing

I need to convert a string like:

```
{:old_id=>{:id=>"12345", :create_date=>Mon, 15 May 2023, :amount=>50.0}, :new_id=>{:id=>nil, :create_date=>"2023-05-15", :amount=>"50.00"}}
```

into a JSON string in Python.

This seems to be a Ruby Hash formatted object, and I don't see a straightforward way to parse it in Python.

(to answer question [How to extract value from json in Snowflake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76510692/how-to-extract-value-from-json-in-snowflake))

Comment: It is not even Ruby `Hash` formatted, it is the _output_ of a Ruby `Hash`; if you feed this into Ruby, it would choke on the date. Whoever recorded this in a database should reconsider their life choices. :P

Comment: You should STRONGLY try not to parse this string, but instead try change how this string is created. This looks like the result of calling `inspect` in a Ruby Hash (which is implicitly called e.g. by the `p` method to output formatted objects to STDOUT). If you want to consume this output with code, you should thus change your Ruby program to emit e.g. JSON  which you can then easily parse in Python.

Comment: Why would you repost this using your previous answer for reference and then repost nearly an identical answer to your own question? Which points back to this question?

Comment: This is the pure Python solution (I know, I hate the initial string too). Maybe there's a better way to parse it in Python? I posted in case someone knows. Meanwhile the question within the Snowflake tag solves how to encapsulate this code within a SQL UDF.

Answer (score 0):

We could solve this with a series of regular expressions:

```py
import re

def ruby_hash_to_json(input_str):
    input_str = input_str.replace('=>', ':')
    input_str = input_str.replace(':nil', ':null')  # JSON uses null, not None

    # Remove weekday from date string and add quotes around date
    input_str = re.sub(r'\w+, (\d{2} \w{3} \d{4})', r'"\1"', input_str)

    # Convert Ruby's symbols (words preceded by a colon) into valid JSON keys (quoted words)
    # This handles symbols both at the beginning of the string and in other positions.
    input_str = re.sub(r'({|, ):(\w+)', r'\1"\2"', input_str)

    return input_str
```